# How to use function based index

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first time that i am trying to use Function based index in oracle. But i don't how to implement it. I searched on net and found simple example related to this like SQL using UPPER function index etc. Though, i found plenty to explanation what is function based index but nothing which explain how it works in case of complex SQL. I have following SQL with sub-select and have really performance issue and when i did some search to improve it then i found that there is something called Function based index. But now i don't know how to use it and how would it improve the performance.
Here is the SQL. Could you somebody help me how to implement Function based index on this SQL (If at all it is possible.)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1( K_ID, KKID, K_SEGMENTS, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7 , COL8,COL9, COL10) 
SELECT DISTINCT K_ID , KKID , K_SEGMENTS , COL1 , COL2 , COL3 , COL4 , COL5 , COL6 , COL7 
, COL8 , COL9 , COL10 
 FROM TABLE2 A 
 , TABLE3 P 
 WHERE P.KEY1 = A.KEY1 
 AND NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT 1 
  FROM TABLE1 B 
  WHERE 1=1 
  AND A.K_ID = B.K_ID 
  AND A.K_SEGMENTS = B.K_SEGMENTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses no "functions" (e.g. UPPER) that might be helped by a function-based index. Your subquery on `TABLE1` is correlated by `K_ID` and `K_SEGMENTS`, so if I was convinced the performance issue was related to this subquery, one of the things I'd consider is adding an ordinary index (i.e. not a FB index) on these two columns.

If you just need to improve the performance of the query, the first thing I'd look at is the explain plan.